# Centralizer of $U(n)$ inside $U(nm)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, classical-groups

Let $n$ and $m$ be two positive integers. There is a canonical inclusion $U(n) \rightarrow U(nm)$ given by the tensor product with the unit matrix $\mathbf{1}_m$.

What is the centralizer of $U(n)$ seen as a subgroup of $U(nm)$?

---

**Edit**: I was asked to provide context, so here it is, but I'm not sure it will be very illuminating for a non-physicist.

**Context**: In physical language, you can consider a field theory with $nm$ free complex scalar fields $\phi_i$, with $i=1,\dots,nm$. The Lagrangian density is then $\sum_i \partial_\mu \phi_i^* \partial^{\mu} \phi_i$. It is left invariant under the action of the unitary group $U(nm)$, the vector $(\phi_i)_{i=1 , \dots , nm}$ being in the fundamental representation.

Now you might want to gauge partially this big symmetry. Here this means you identify a subgroup $U(n) \subset U(nm)$ and consider the combinations of the $\phi_i$ that are invariant under $U(n)$. A way to visualize that is to see the fields $\phi_i$ as the entries of an $n \times m$ where $U(n)$ acts by left multiplication. Then it is obvious that there is also a group $U(m)$ which acts by right multiplication on this matrix, and the two actions commute. Therefore, the centralizer of $U(n)$ contains $U(m)$.

My question can then be re-formulated as: is the centralizer equal to $U(m)$, or bigger?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I thought on the contrary that it was better to be as concise and precise as possible (in addition to posting only one question by post, and other similar recommendations). I'm going to edit to add context and my partial answer so far.

Comment: I don't have a reference to hand but the centralizer in ${\rm GL}(n,K)$ of the direct sum of $m$ copies of an absolutely irreducible representation of degree $m$ is ${\rm GL}(m,K)$, coming from the tensor product. So in your case the centralizer of $U(n)$ in ${\rm GL}(mn,{\mathbb C})$ is ${\rm GL}(m,{\mathbb C})$, and I think the intersection of that with $U(mn)$ is just $U(m)$. So I think the answer to your question is yes, but I am not completely certain.